# Python - Pandas GroupBy Iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I have an extract of a large dataframe below:

```
      ticker       date  buy_fg  sell_fg hold_fg action
18360    CXP 2003-08-22     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18361    CXP 2003-08-29     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18362    CXP 2003-09-05     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18363    CXP 2003-09-12     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18364    CXP 2003-09-19     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18365    CXP 2003-09-26     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18366    CXP 2003-10-03     1.0      0.0       1    BUY
18367    DDF 1999-12-31     0.0      2.0     ZZZ   SELL
18368    DDF 2000-01-07     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18369    DDF 2000-01-14     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
```

The `action` field was produced using the following code:

```
buy_flag = 0
hold_flag = 0
lis = []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if buy_flag == 1 and row['sell_fg'] == 2:
        lis.append('SELL')
        buy_flag = 0
        hold_flag = 0
    elif hold_flag == 1 and row['sell_fg'] == 2:
        lis.append('SELL')
        hold_flag = 0
        buy_flag = 0
    elif buy_flag == 1 and row['hold_fg'] == 3:
        lis.append('HOLD')
        hold_flag = 1
    elif buy_flag == 1 and row['hold_fg'] == 1:
        lis.append('HOLD')
        hold_flag = 1
    elif row['buy_fg'] == 1:
        lis.append('BUY')
        buy_flag = 1
    else:
        lis.append('NIL')

df['action'] = lis
```

However, as you can see row 18367 has an incorrect action - it is showing SELL as opposed to NIL. I believe this is because my code (above) iterates through each row in the dataframe and does not consider that the ticker has changed from CXP to DDF (i.e. new group).

I need help with two aspect:
-Can someone please help me to figure out how to modify this code to groupby `ticker`?
-If it's the last row of each group - it is always a `SELL`

Otherwise, the code works perfectly.

Expected output is below:

```
      ticker       date  buy_fg  sell_fg hold_fg action
18360    CXP 2003-08-22     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18361    CXP 2003-08-29     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18362    CXP 2003-09-05     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18363    CXP 2003-09-12     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18364    CXP 2003-09-19     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18365    CXP 2003-09-26     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18366    CXP 2003-10-03     1.0      0.0       1    SELL
18367    DDF 1999-12-31     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18368    DDF 2000-01-07     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18369    DDF 2000-01-14     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
```

Comment: use groupby and idmax()?

Comment: will all `buy-fg = 0` and `sell_fg = 2.0` result in `NIL` and does all last row for a group result in `SELL`.  Is there a generic option for the `buy_fg`, `sell_fg`, and `hold_fg` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track `per ticker`, `per flag`. Once you do that you may need to review your logic to make sure it sets the correct flags, but this should work:

```
ticker = {}
lis = []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.ticker not in ticker:
        ticker[row.ticker] = {}
        ticker[row.ticker]['buy_flag'] = 0
        ticker[row.ticker]['sell_flag'] = 0
        ticker[row.ticker]['hold_flag'] = 0
        
    if ticker[row.ticker]['buy_flag'] == 1 and row['sell_fg'] == 2:
        lis.append('SELL')
        ticker[row.ticker]['buy_flag'] = 0
        ticker[row.ticker]['hold_flag'] = 0
    elif ticker[row.ticker]['hold_flag'] == 1 and row['sell_fg'] == 2:
        lis.append('SELL')
        ticker[row.ticker]['hold_flag'] = 0
        ticker[row.ticker]['buy_flag'] = 0
    elif ticker[row.ticker]['buy_flag'] == 1 and row['hold_fg'] == 3:
        lis.append('HOLD')
        ticker[row.ticker]['hold_flag'] = 1
    elif buy_flag == 1 and row['hold_fg'] == 1:
        lis.append('HOLD')
        ticker[row.ticker]['hold_flag'] = 1
    elif row['buy_fg'] == 1:
        lis.append('BUY')
        ticker[row.ticker]['buy_flag'] = 1
    else:
        lis.append('NIL')

>>> df['action'] = lis
>>> df
      ticker        date  buy_fg  sell_fg hold_fg action
18360    CXP  2003-08-22     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18361    CXP  2003-08-29     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18362    CXP  2003-09-05     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18363    CXP  2003-09-12     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18364    CXP  2003-09-19     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18365    CXP  2003-09-26     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18366    CXP  2003-10-03     1.0      0.0       1    BUY
18367    DDF  1999-12-31     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18368    DDF  2000-01-07     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
18369    DDF  2000-01-14     0.0      2.0     ZZZ    NIL
```

This will create global dictionary with all the positions, per ticker:

```
>>> ticker
{'CXP': {'buy_flag': 1, 'sell_flag': 0, 'hold_flag': 0},
 'DDF': {'buy_flag': 0, 'sell_flag': 0, 'hold_flag': 0}}
```

You may need to change/amend the logic of your main script as I didn't spent too much time on it, simply re-worked it to match what you need.